# Why can’t I save a file after editing in Nano through SSH?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, nano

I created Raspbian server and connected to it with SSH from my machine. When I try to modify the file using Nano, I can not get past “File Name to Write prompt.

[image: Where I get stuck]

I have tried using `nano filename` and also `sudo nano filename` and both times it will not let me save file. I only hear ding on my machine when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Only option I can do at that point is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel and exit without saving.

Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I have not resolved issue with my system, however, I was able to connect from different system using different SSH client and it worked without any issues. My guess there is problem with SSH client and some setting on raspberry pi that prevented me from saving it. Will try some stuff in the article later to see if it is related to UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried using `nano filename` and also `sudo nano filename` and both times it will not let me save file. I only hear ding on my machine when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Well, attempting to use `sudo` in a case like this is ridiculous since if you can get onto a server and run nano you should be able to save it as a normal user.

My guess is there is some Terminal emulation issue happening. Either the configuration of the Terminal software you are using to connect to the server is not exactly correct, or the SSH server on the remote server has configuration issues as well. Might be a UTF-8 issue so [look here for some insight](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21606&p=504375). Or perhaps this is a [locale setting issue as explained here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22376/shell-and-ssh-locale-issues-on-raspbian).